# fetch data with count and group by in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `mail_details`

```
|   mail_id   | sent_time          |  failed_time       | mail_type   |
|   (bigint)  |  (timestamp)       |    (timestamp)     |  (varvharing)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-t       
|    2        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-t
|    3        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-m
|    4        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-p
|    5        | null(default)      |  2020-02-05        |   type-p
|    6        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-m
|    8        | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-m
|    9        | null(default)      |  2020-02-05        |   type-m
|    10       | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-n
|    11       | 2020-02-05         |  null(default)     |   type-n
```

Whenever the mail sent to the user I updated `sent_time` or mail sent failed I update `failed_time`

Now I want to fetch `total number of mail sent (count) and the total number of mail failed (count)` with the `respective date` where mail_type=(type_t or type_p or type_m or type_n)

output will be like

```
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
|date                 |tatal_sent_mail |tatal_failed_mail|
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
|2020-05-05           |8               |2               |
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I have tried with count but did not work. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Hi @zealous I am beginner and tried with count and group by but it did not wored

Comment: @bala - Could you try all answers and comment what works and what doesn't? You should try for a data for which an entry for a date exists sent_time and doesn't for failed_time and vice versa to have a 100% coverage on your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summarise using aggregate filters, and coalesce the dates between columns.

```
SELECT
  coalesce(sent_time, failed_time) AS date,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE sent_time IS NOT NULL) AS total_sent_mail,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE failed_time IS NOT NULL) AS total_failed_mail
FROM mail_details
WHERE mail_type IN ('type_t','type_p','type_m','type_n')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

If you need rows for missing dates, you would need to resort to using generate_series().

Comment: why it gives an extra row with blank date and 0 counts @Thom Brown

Comment: Do you have a row where both sent_mail and failed_mail are NULL?  If you do, you can just filter that out in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Ok got it. One more thing is that sent_time is a timestamp so for sent time 2020-05-08 01:10:53.847912 and 2020-05-08 01:30:53.847912 it returns two rows with count 1 and 1 but I want it to consider only date not time(h:s:i) and returns one row with count 2. @Thom Brown

Comment: You can just cast them to dates, so use sent_time::date, failed_time::date in the coalesce parameters.  No need to do that in the FILTER clause though.

Answer (score 1):

I would unpivot using a lateral `join` and aggregate:

```
select time::date, sum(is_sent), sum(is_fail)
from mail_details md cross join lateral
     (values (sent_time, (sent_time is not null)::int, 0)
             (failed_time, 0, (failed is not null)::int)
     ) v(time, is_sent, is_fail)
where t.time is not null and
      md.mail_type in ('type_t','type_p','type_m','type_n')
group by time::date
```

Comment: I did not got this query i think you have missed where mail_type

Comment: I did not got this query i think you have missed where mail_type @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @bala . . . It was not clear to me if that really required filtering.  You listed all the mail types in your sample data, so no filtering seemed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using a union, this should do it:

```sql
SELECT  dt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN event == 'SENT' then 1 else 0 end) total_sent_mail,
        SUM(CASE WHEN event == 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) total_failed_mail,
FROM
    (   SELECT  'SENT' as event,
                sent_time as dt 
        FROM    mail_details
        WHERE   sent_time IS NOT NULL   )
    UNION ALL
    (   SELECT  'FAIL' as event,
                failed_time as dt
        FROM    mail_details
        WHERE   failed_time IS NOT NULL  )
GROUP BY dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one using FULL OUTER JOIN on the inline view,

```
select sent_time as date,tatal_sent_mail,tatal_failed_mail
from 
(select sent_time,count(1) tatal_sent_mail
where mail_type in ('type_t','type_p','type_m','type_n')
group by sent_time) sent_data
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select failed_time Final_date,count(1) tatal_failed_mail
where mail_type in ('type_t','type_p','type_m','type_n')
group by failed_time) failed_Data
ON sent_data.sent_time = failed_Data.failed_time
```